# How to use subprocess.Popen to start a new task on a remote computer with ssh

Tags: python, ssh

Take a look at this:

```
ssh_cmd = ["ssh", "pi@" + "100.117.210.18", "roslaunch minirover mr_bru_bringup.launch"]
cmd1 = subprocess.Popen(" ".join(ssh_cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd1_out = cmd1.stdout.read()
print(cmd1_out)
```

It turns out that roslaunch starts a long running process on the ssh'd computer. The above sequence works, but doesn't complete.

I would like to let it run but have the above sequence complete so that I can issue another ssh command which will start another shell.

Not sure how to do this after quite a bit of experimentation.

Comment: Have you tried putting `&` at the end of the command?  That is the usual way to run a command in the background.

Comment: I did and it didn't seem to work.